# Can a 5th level Pact of the blade warlock, use his action to grapple, then attack twice with his pact weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

By RAW, when I use a grapple:

> "**Grappling**
>
> When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it,
> you can use the Attack action..."

And the 5th level eldrich invocation:

> "**Thirsting Blade**
>
> Prerequisite: 5th level, Pact o f the Blade feature
>
> You can attack with your pact weapon twice, instead of
> once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn."

So, by RAW: If it says "instead", then otherwise (A.K.A. without that eldrich invocation) the rule would be: "You can attack with your pact weapon once **whenever** you take the Attack action on your turn." And that would allow the player to grapple **and** attack with his pact weapon. Because when he grapples he uses the attack action, and then trigger the eldrich invocation. From that perspective, with this eldrich invocation, you can grapple and then attack with your pact weapon twice. Is that interpretation right?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: The order of the actions makes it different.

Comment: Hmm... I suppose so

Comment: If I first grapple, then I have used the Attack action and trigger the eldrich invocation.

Answer (score 14):

### If you've used your attack to grapple, you don't qualify for Thirsting Blade

Thirsting blade lets you replace one attack with the pact weapon with two.

> You can attack with your pact weapon twice, *instead of once*

However, when you make a grapple using the Attack action you aren't taking any attacks with the pact weapon (you are making the special grapple attack instead). You therefore don't have the one pact weapon to replace with two.

To elaborate; a grapple is

> a special melee attack.

you can take with the Attack action. When you take the Attack action, you can normally make one attack, where attacking with the special melee attack is one of your options. This isn't exceptionally well spelled out by the text as written, but you don't get a free grapple attempt unless you have an Extra Attack feature (in which case it explicitly replaces one your attacks).

---

A kinder reading of Thirsting Blade would let the grapple option replace one of your two attacks;

> If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them.

Leaving you with one attack with the pact weapon after the grapple attempt. However, this ignores the restriction written into the Thirsting Blade feature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119398/discussion-between-khadzul-warrev-and-someone-evil).

Answer (score 8):

### No, Thirsting Blade replaces the attack you'd make otherwise.

Thirsting Blade lets you attack with your weapon twice instead of once. Under a (probably excessively) generous reading, you can attack with your weapon twice instead of attacking *by any means* once. But what you can't do is attack with your weapon twice and *also* attack once by some other means.

"Instead" means "in place of". Instead of attacking once (such as making a grapple), you can attack twice with your pact weapon.

Comment: The term "instead" reffers to "attack with your pact weapon" and not just "Attack"

Comment: @khadzulwarrev That doesn't matter. If you attack twice with your pact weapon instead of grappling, you are not grappling. If you attack twice with your pact weapon instead of attacking once with your pact weapon, you are also not grappling.

Comment: I will try to make it clear: If it says "instead", then otherwise (A.K.A. without that eldrich invocation) the rule is: "You can attack with your pact weapon once whenever you take the Attack action on your turn."
And that would allow the player to grapple and attack with his pact weapon. Because when he grapples he uses the attack action.

Comment: There is no such rule. There's a general rule that you can attack with a weapon when you take the Attack action, but if you grapple, you are doing that instead of attacking with a weapon.

Comment: Existing that rule or not, the point here is the phrasing. The "instead" means that otherwise that would be the rule, and if in the other situation you could grapple and then attack with your pact weapon, now you can grapple and then attack twice.

Comment: If the rule was just: "You can attack twice with your pact weapon whenever you take the Attack action on your turn." Could you grapple and then attack with your pact weapon twice?